# Google Sheet Average Based on Column Dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to find the average of all the attendees that participated in a 2v2 tournament. So if column C = `2v2`, then I need to collect all of the rows that are 2v2 tourneys and average out the `G` columns attendees.
Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AVERAGEIF` instead

```
=AVERAGEIF(C2:C125,"="&"2v2",G2:G125)
```

Learn more about [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256529)

Comment: Thanks! Worked very well, added a FLOOR.MATH to it and now everything looks super good!